# Numpy can be imported in cmd but not in Python Shell

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, cmd, module

I'm running Python 2.7.6. Numpy was installed using `conda install numpy` in cmd. The installation was successfully completed. Then I tested the numpy module in cmd, it did work. However, when I used Python Shell to import the numpy module, it said "no module named numpy."

I can't fix it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You probably have multiple python version installed, one of which has numpy, while the other doesn't :)

Comment: Yeah, I have Python 3.3 installed. Should I remove it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @B8vrede

Comment: Removing shouldn't be necessary just make sure that you run the right version or install numpy for both version :)

Comment: Ok, I'll install numpy for Python 3.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. :-) @B8vrede

Comment: Hi, could you please suggest the version of numpy that work for python 3.3? @B8vrede thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think most recent version will work, but you will have to google that. Good luck!